# Using an SQL database to manage unique id's for cloud firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, unique-id

I’m looking for a way to get unique but human readable collection document id’s (account-id and such). Firestore does not enforce id uniqueness, but it occurs to me that I could (in principle) use an SQL database for the sole purpose of creating and maintaining unique id’s. SQLite would even do for this purpose. Of course I’d like all to be hosted in the Firebase Cloud, and I need it to be cheap, particularly given the limited scope of the SQL db usage.

Any advice?

Comment: Why do you say that "Firestore does not enforce id uniqueness"? Is it about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53119133/firestore-generated-unique-ids-for-more-then-1-collection/53119209#53119209)?

Comment: For, say, usernames used as firestore doc id's. I got the info i need here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/XkWb08RoPhg/yv8d_6GvCQAJ