# How unique are document id of Firestore? Considering more than million document

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, android-database

I am trying to get the auto-generated ID from the DocumentReference Object

```
DocumentReference docref = db.collection("users").document(); 
String ID = check.getID();
```

The question is since the ID's are generated at client side there can be chances that 2 ID in firestore are similar to each other when their are more than a million document in a collection and when I use .set() the document gets updated.
***I have seen other answer but none solved my doubt.***

Comment: Check also **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53119133/firestore-generated-unique-ids-for-more-then-1-collection)** out.

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing, a Firestore Auto ID (at least in the [JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/firestore/src/util/misc.ts#L25-L37)) is constructed from 20 random characters selected from the characters `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9` - so 20 characters chosen from 62 possible characters.

This means that there are `62^20` (or `7.01e35`) different possible combinations.

This is very similar to the `2^120` possible combinations used in the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html) (that also use the `-` and `_` characters for `64^20` possible combinations).

The main difference between RTDB's Push IDs and Firestore's Auto IDs is that the auto ids are not encoded according to the device timestamp - all ~120 bits are random.

So, statistically it is very unlikely that you will encounter a collision. But you can always use your own system to generate your own IDs or use some drop in `uuid` package to generate a 128-bit or greater ID.

Comment: You would have to generate 1.3 quintillion auto ids to have a 50% probability of a collision. You'd have to generate 163 quadrillion auto ids to have 1% probability of a collision.

Comment: Not only javascript any programming language

Comment: To build on @samthecodingman 's answer with a relatable number, to have a 1% probability of collision, you'd need (one million x one billion = one quadrillion) documents in the same collection. So if you have a chat app where each chat is a document in a collection, and there are 1 billion chats, you'd need to multiply the number of chats by 1 million to get a 1% chance of collision.